# Calculation of the Cosets of the Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $g:\Bbb{Z}_3 \times\Bbb{Z}_4 \to \Bbb{Z}_3$ where $g((a,b)) =a$ .

What are the cosets of the kernel? I understand that a kernel is the set of elements that map to the identity element. Any assistance or solutions are welcome.

Comment: What is the kernel in this particular case? When you have figured that out, can you come up with some explicit cosets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_4$.
The kernel of $g$ is
$$K=\{\,(a,b)\in G\,\mid\, g((a,b))=0\,\} = \{\,(a,b)\in G\,\mid\, a = 0\,\} = \{0\}\times\mathbb Z_4\text.$$
For each $(a,b)\in G$, its corresponding coset has the form
$$(a,b)K=\{\,(a,b)+(c,d)\,\mid\,(c,d)\in K\,\}=\{\,(a,b+d)\,\mid\,d\in\mathbb Z_4\,\}=\{a\}\times\mathbb Z_4\text.$$
Therefore, the factor group $G/K$ (which is just the set of all cosets) is
$$G/K=\{\,gK\,\mid\,g\in G\,\}=\{\,\{a\}\times\mathbb Z_4\,\mid\,a\in\mathbb Z_3\,\}\cong\mathbb Z_3\text.$$